# javafx.scene.Scene cannot be cast to javafx.scene.layout.Pane

Tags: javafx, fxml

Hi guys i'm new to javafx build and i'm trying to cast a Pane but can't seem to work and i don't know why, I hope you can help me, if so thanks!

```
  package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            Pane root = (Pane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Interface.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and the errors i get are

```
WARNING: Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 11.0.1 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.231
java.lang.ClassCastException: javafx.scene.Scene cannot be cast to javafx.scene.layout.Pane
    at application.Main.start(Main.java:14)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$8(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$7(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$5(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$6(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$4(WinApplication.java:186)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I used Scenebuilder to build the fxml file

Comment: Presumably your FXML file defines a `Scene` as the root element. A `Scene` is not a `Pane`.

Comment: `SceneBuilder` shouldn't porduce fxmls with `<Scene>` root elements though. However there's no other place with a cast in `start`...

Comment: It would probably help to post the FXML file.

Comment: @James_D  thanks a lot ! it works now, it was kinda dumb but now i know, thanks a lot guys !

Comment: @James_D I unwrapped the Pane from the Stage and it works fine now :D